# Using ASP.NET Core MVC, how do I display an image?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to display an image for a gallery page I am creating. I'm very new to ASP.NET Core MVC. I saved the image in the same folder that my project is in.

This is what I have in my view file:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Gallery";
}
<h2>Gallery Page</h2>
<img src="myImage.jpg" height="113" width="113" border="0" />
```

This is my gallery function in my controller:

```
public IActionResult Gallery()
{
    return View();
}
```

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FezzB.png)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: asp-net core? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0 TLDR; Save the image file into wwwroot/, `app.UseStaticFiles();`, `src="~/myImage.jpg"`.

Answer (score 2):

In the img src you have directly gave the image name instead of create a new image folder and add the image file into that folder. change the html code as given below.

`<img src="~/Folder Name/myImage.jpg" height="113" width="113" border="0" />`